# warning.expression prevents last.warning from update

Tags: r

I'm interested in trying to manipulate warnings on call *without* creating support infrastructure around a method. That is, I need to be able to *catch* the warning without resorting to wrapping code with:

```
tryCatch(..., warning = function() { action() } )
```

I believe I can do this using the [`warning.expression`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/options.html) handler.

However, the issue I am running into is the [`last.warning`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/warning.html) when invoked during the warning dispatch of [`warning.expression`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/options.html) fails to retrieve the latest warning.

For example:

```
warning_handler = function() {
  if (exists("last.warning", baseenv()) &&
      !is.null(last.warning)) {
    warning_contents =  names(last.warning)
  } else {
    warning_contents =  NA
  }

  message(warning_contents)
}


options(warning.expression = quote({ warning_handler() }))

warning("test1")
# test1
warning("testing2")
# test1
warning("sampletest3")
# test1
```

If I revert to using the default handler, e.g. `NULL`, then the message is updated at the cost of not being able to interact with it.

```
options(warning.expression = NULL)

warning("test1")
# Warning message:
# test1
warning("testing2")
# Warning message:
# testing2
warning("sampletest3")
# Warning message:
# sampletest3
```

Am I missing something related to the handler or?

Answer (score 3):

Adding a `warning.expression` almost certainly interferes with the warning collection mechanism.  I'm not 100% certain about this, but if you look at (R.3.4.0, I have an old copy of the sources), you can see at errors.c@335:

```
static void vwarningcall_dflt(SEXP call, const char *format, va_list ap)
{
    int w;
    SEXP names, s;
    const char *dcall;
    char buf[BUFSIZE];
    RCNTXT *cptr;
    RCNTXT cntxt;

    if (inWarning)
        return;

    s = GetOption1(install("warning.expression"));
    if( s != R_NilValue ) {
        if( !isLanguage(s) &&  ! isExpression(s) )
            error(_("invalid option \"warning.expression\""));
        cptr = R_GlobalContext;
        while ( !(cptr->callflag & CTXT_FUNCTION) && cptr->callflag )
            cptr = cptr->nextcontext;
        eval(s, cptr->cloenv);
        return;
    }
  // ... snip ...


    else if(w == 0) {   /* collect them */
        if(!R_CollectWarnings) setupwarnings();
        if(R_CollectWarnings < R_nwarnings) {
            SET_VECTOR_ELT(R_Warnings, R_CollectWarnings, call);
            Rvsnprintf(buf, min(BUFSIZE, R_WarnLength+1), format, ap);
  // ... snip ...
}
```

So the part after the `return` doesn't run.

And it looks like `last.value` is populated by `printWarnings` in errors.c@466, so this either happens after the `warning.expressions` handler, or more likely, not at all:

```
attribute_hidden
void PrintWarnings(void)
{
  // ... snip to very end of fun ...

    /* now truncate and install last.warning */
    PROTECT(s = allocVector(VECSXP, R_CollectWarnings));
    PROTECT(t = allocVector(STRSXP, R_CollectWarnings));
    names = CAR(ATTRIB(R_Warnings));
    for(i = 0; i < R_CollectWarnings; i++) {
        SET_VECTOR_ELT(s, i, VECTOR_ELT(R_Warnings, i));
        SET_STRING_ELT(t, i, STRING_ELT(names, i));
    }
    setAttrib(s, R_NamesSymbol, t);
    SET_SYMVALUE(install("last.warning"), s);
    UNPROTECT(2);

    endcontext(&cntxt);

    inPrintWarnings = 0;
    R_CollectWarnings = 0;
    R_Warnings = R_NilValue;
    return;
}
```

So it is likely that's what going on.  I haven't worked through the flow patterns so it's possible I'm wrong.  If I'm right it seems like there isn't a way to get the warning info from `warning.expression`.

Beyond that, note that `last.warning` is documented as being undocumented, FWIW.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer courtesy of @lionel in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/40773805#40773805) was: to install a warning handler at top level, which you can do by calling into internal functions with `.Internal()`

```
handlers <- list(warning = function(cnd) cat("hello\n")) 
classes <- names(handlers) 
.Internal(.addCondHands(classes, handlers, globalenv(), NULL, TRUE)) 

warn("plop")
```

The only downside to this approach is CRAN would reject a package on submission due to the internal call.