# How to use the `sink` function within another function in R?

Tags: r, sink

I have a function `fun` that relies on an external function `external` (i.e., from some package). How can I collect all the warnings that come out of `external` in a character vector?

This is a minimal setup:

```r
# External function from another package.
external <- function() {
    warning("warning from external...")
}


# Function meant to capture the warnings.
fun <- function() {
    # Create variable to store the warnings.
    warns <- vector("character")

    # Create connection for the sink.
    connection <- textConnection("warns", "wr", local = TRUE)

    # Start collecting.
    sink(connection, type = "message")

    # Call external function and produce a warning.
    external()

    # Reset the sink.
    sink(type = "message")

    # Close the connection.
    close(connection)

    return(warns)
}
```

The output, however looks like this:

```r
x <- fun()
# Warning message:
# In external() : warning from external...

print(x)
# character(0)
```

I am not interested in `suppressWarnings`, but rather to log these warnings. When I use `sink` outside of a function it seems to work, just as indicated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27444424/5252007).

Comment: Do you know `warnings` are already logged?

Comment: You mean in the `last.warning` created by R?

Comment: Yes, but you might also want to look at the option `warning.expression` to override the behaviour on a warning - i.e. log rather than print.

Comment: @James, can you expand a little bit? I think this approach is very interesting!

Comment: I just found out that *'If `warn` is zero (the default) warnings are stored until the top–level function returns.'* Setting it to `1` before the sink allowed for the warnings to be captured by the sink. But I am very curious the `warning.expression` path.

Comment: It might not be possible unfortunately, there's a discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48071718/warning-expression-prevents-last-warning-from-update

Comment: Reading it right now. I think I get the idea. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tryCatch` for this:

```
fun <- function() {
  tryCatch(external(), warning = function(my_warn) my_warn$message)
}

x <-fun()

x
# [1] "warning from external..."
```

Comment: I was completely oblivious to the `warning` argument of `tryCatch`. Good one!

Comment: Can you please take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57669971/5252007) inspired by your answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try `evaluate()` function from `evaluate` package, if you want to store warnings in a character vector:

```
external <- function() {
  warning("warning from external...")
}

# Function meant to capture the warnings.
fun <- function() {
   #some operation
   x=1+2;
   warnings_ls = evaluate::evaluate(external())
   return(list(value=x,warn=warnings_ls))
}

x <- fun()

> a$warn[[1]]$src
[1] "warning from external..."

> a$value
[1] 3
```

Comment: Thanks, useful to know about `evaluate` package!

Answer (score 1):

Supplementing the answers above, the `warn` option (see `?options`) says:

> sets the handling of warning messages. If `warn` is negative all warnings are ignored. **If `warn` is zero (the default) warnings are stored until the top–level function returns.** If 10 or fewer warnings were signalled they will be printed otherwise a message saying how many were signalled. An object called `last.warning` is created and can be printed through the function `warnings`. **If warn is one, warnings are printed as they occur.** If `warn` is two or larger all warnings are turned into errors.

In that sense, setting `options(warn = 1)` before the `sink` makes it possible for the warning messages can be captured. The `warn` can be reverted to default after resetting the `sink` (i.e., `options(warn = 0)`). Then, `fun` would look something like:

```r
fun <- function() {
    # Print warnings as they occur.
    options(warn = 1)

    # Create variable to store the warnings.
    warns <- vector("character")

    # Create connection for the sink.
    connection <- textConnection("warns", "wr", local = TRUE)

    # Start collecting.
    sink(connection, type = "message")

    # Call external function and produce a warning.
    external()

    # Reset the sink.
    sink(type = "message")

    # Close the connection.
    close(connection)

    # Restore default warning behavior.
    options(warn = 0)

    return(warns)
}
```

With the following output:

```r
fun()
# [1] "Warning in external() : warning from external..."
```